# How to reduce the image file size after resizing

Tags: ios, image, xamarin, size

I used the code below I wrote to reduce the image size and keep the aspect ratio. The image i have resized is 1920 * 1275 1.9mbytes and original image size is 4288 × 2848 1.8mbytes. The image size got resized but not the file sized. How do i reduced the file size?

At the moment, I want to keep the quality of the image.

```
var sourceImage = new UIImage(source); 
        var sourceSize = sourceImage.Size; 
        var maxResizeFactor = Math.Max(targetWidth / sourceSize.Width, targetHeight / sourceSize.Height);
        if (maxResizeFactor > 1) return source;

        var ratioImage = sourceSize.Width / sourceSize.Height;
        var ratioScreen = targetWidth / targetHeight;
        var newWidth = 0.0f;
        var newHeight = 0.0f;

        if (ratioScreen > ratioImage)
        {
            newWidth = (float)(sourceSize.Width * (targetHeight / sourceSize.Height));
            newHeight = targetHeight;
        }
        else 
        {
            newWidth = targetWidth;
            newHeight = (float)(sourceSize.Height * (targetWidth / sourceSize.Width));
        }

        UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new SizeF((float) newWidth, (float) newHeight));
        sourceImage.Draw(new RectangleF(0, 0, (float)newWidth, (float)newHeight));
        var resultImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

        NSError error;
        if (MimeType.IsPNG(source))
            resultImage.AsPNG().Save(destination, true, out error);
        else
            resultImage.AsJPEG().Save(destination, true, out error);

        if (error != null)
            return source;
        else
            return destination;
```

Comment: Take a look at `AsJPEG()`. You can set a compressionQuality as a parameter.

Comment: yes i looked at that too.. I thought the file size will change as the image resized.